# Problems with running webdriver-manager start --standalone on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, protractor

I am configuring to run a Protractor test and below are the steps added in Azure devops

[image]

When I run this pipeline, it gets struck at webdriver-manager start --standalone. Not coming out of it so that it runs the next command to start test.

[image]

Error Log

```
2021-03-12T09:02:39.2180071Z ##[section]Starting: Run Test Cases
2021-03-12T09:02:39.3078252Z ==============================================================================
2021-03-12T09:02:39.3082840Z Task         : Command line
2021-03-12T09:02:39.3085464Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2021-03-12T09:02:39.3086081Z Version      : 2.182.0
2021-03-12T09:02:39.3086701Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-03-12T09:02:39.3087524Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2021-03-12T09:02:39.3088140Z ==============================================================================
2021-03-12T09:02:40.7279581Z Generating script.
2021-03-12T09:02:40.7467500Z Script contents:
2021-03-12T09:02:40.7486434Z node node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor.conf.js
2021-03-12T09:02:40.7928490Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2021-03-12T09:02:40.8274945Z ##[command]"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\91ab13f0-924e-4e63-a124-869764af15df.cmd""
2021-03-12T09:02:42.4610822Z [09:02:42] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
2021-03-12T09:02:42.4614093Z [09:02:42] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5634194Z [09:02:43] E/launcher - Error code: 135
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5635264Z [09:02:43] E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5636368Z [09:02:43] E/launcher - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5638525Z     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:238:15)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5640056Z     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5642323Z     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5643094Z     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5643710Z     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5644453Z     at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5645162Z     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5645806Z From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5646642Z     at Function.createSession (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5648679Z     at Function.createSession (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:761:15)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5649636Z     at createDriver (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:170:33)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5650518Z     at Builder.build (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:626:16)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5651614Z     at Hosted.getNewDriver (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:53:33)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5652586Z     at Runner.createBrowser (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5653422Z     at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5654331Z     at _fulfilled (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5655184Z     at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5656122Z     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
2021-03-12T09:02:43.5658296Z [09:02:43] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
2021-03-12T09:02:43.6876129Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '135'.
2021-03-12T09:02:43.7575403Z ##[section]Finishing: Run Test Cases
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. We dont need an explict step to start Webdriver and also i had to comment a line in config.js

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Not coming out of it so that it runs the next command to start test.

The net command is the task `Run Test Cases`, right? If yes, we could click the task and expand the tab `Control Options` and ensure the field `Run this task` is set to `Even if a previous task has failed, unless the build was canceled`.

Then if the task `Webdriver Start` fails, the pipeline will continue to run the next task `Run Test Cases`.

[image]

**Update1**

> Not coming out of it so that it runs the next command to start test.

The initial problem has been solved.

Since you have not started or webdriver not get started correctly, we could see the error issue: `ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444`. If the previous task successfully runs Webdriver, we will not see the error message.

We need ensure the Webdriver start and then run the Protractor test.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. But here the previous task is not failing, its just not coming out of that or completing the task

Comment: Hi @SamK, According to the screenshot you shared, the previous task status seems to have been canceled, right? We just need to change the field value to  `Even if a previous task has failed, even if the build was canceled`. Or we could check the previous task status and configure custom condition. You could try it, it should be work.

Comment: What i did was, i set a timeout of 1 min to come out of that task. Also, modified the Test Run task as per your suggetions. But, i am getting the Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444

Comment: Do you mind sharing the detail log in the issue description?

Comment: add the raw log

Comment: Hi @SamK, Got the issue, I have updated the answer, check the update1

Comment: Webdriver is getting started if you see the screen shot.. but on Azure, its not moving to next task to run the test

Comment: Why do not add the webdriver-manager start in the task Run Test Cases, and try it again? According to the error message, it seems cannot found the webdriver

Comment: Please ensure the previous task is successful, then run the test